# Generics applied on interface Java

Tags: java, rest, generics

I tried to write this interface

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
public interface Command<T extends Enum<T> & Command> {
    default public T getCommand(String cmd) {
         final Class<? extends Enum> enumType = T.class;
         return T.valueOf(enumType, cmd);
    }
}
```

but doesn't compile. Why?

I want use this interface to implement Enum like this:

```
public enum RestCommand implements Command<RestCommand> {
    GET, PUT, POST, DELETE;
}
```

Comment: It's not erasure but it's similar, iirc the first type will take priority (in the `T extends`). Try switching them or even removing the `Enum<T>` entirely and just checking `this.getClass().isEnum()` for your default.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn what [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) is.

Comment: @Rogue it is erasure that stops `T.class` (and `T.valueOf`) from compiling.

Comment: There's multiple issues at stake here, that's one of them as well. Problem I'm referring to is relevant for the specific... "usability" of T.

Answer (score 2):

Because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you can't invoke methods on type variables like you can with static members of classes:

```
String.class  // OK
T.class       // Compiler error, because T is unknown at compile time.
```

You can work around this by passing in `enumType` as a parameter to the method:

```
public interface Command<T extends Enum<T> & Command<T>> {
  default public T getCommand(String cmd, Class<T> enumType) {
    return Enum.valueOf(enumType, cmd);
  }
}
```

But it's not really clear what you gain through this: in your `enum`, you now need an instance of the enum to access an instance of the enum:

```
GET.getCommand("POST", RestCommand.class);
```

which is awkward: you shouldn't need a `GET` to get the `POST`.

Basically, the `enum` shouldn't implement the `Command` interface; it's really a `CommandFactory` (or something like that):

```
class RestCommandFactory implements CommandFactory<RestCommand> {}
```

since you're using it to get the instances of `RestCommand`.